# how to subscribe to an Observable returned from ngrx's Entity Data Service

Tags: angular, ngrx, rxjs-observables, ngrx-entity, angular-ngrx-data

i have a service called TransactionEntityService derived from EntityCollectionServiceBase for a model called Transaction.

```
export class TransactionEntityService
extends EntityCollectionServiceBase<Transaction> {
```

I am using TransactionDataService to override default behavior of DefaultDataService .
In AppModule TransactionDataService is registered like this

```
    export class AppModule {
  constructor(
    private eds: EntityDefinitionService,
    private entityDataService: EntityDataService,
    private transactionsDataService: TransactionsDataService
  ) {
    eds.registerMetadataMap(entityMetadata);

    entityDataService.registerService('Transaction', transactionsDataService);
  }
}
```

and TransactionsDataService overrides getAll like below.

```
    export class TransactionsDataService extends DefaultDataService<Transaction> {
  constructor(
    http: HttpClient,
    httpUrlGenerator: HttpUrlGenerator,
    private notifyService: NotificationService
  ) {
    super('Transaction', http, httpUrlGenerator);
  }
  getAll(): Observable<Transaction[]> {
    return this.http
      .get<ApiResponse>('https://localhost:xxxx/transaction/GetLastSixMonth')
      .pipe(
        tap((data) => {
          this.notifyService.showSuccess(data.message, 'Sucess');
        }),
        map((res) => res.result),
        catchError((err) => {
          this.notifyService.showError(
            'Error While Six Month Transactions',
            'Error'
          );
          return of();
        })
      );
  }
```

The "$entitie" property of entity service is returning proper result after calling the api. and i am filtering that result to get count of something in an observable called last6MonthDepositCount$.

```
  this.last6MonthDepositCount$ = this.transactionsEntityService.entities$.pipe(
  map((transactions) => {
    const res = transactions.filter(
      (transaction) =>
        transaction.transactionType === TransactionType.Deposit
    ).length;
    return res;
  })//,
 // tap((val) => this.depositCount = val)
);
```

in the html i can use this observable

```
{{ last6MonthDepositCount$  | async }}
```

it works.

what should i do to use the value of this observable in another variable in my code ?

```
this.last6MonthDepositCount$.subscribe(x => this.dipositCount = x);
```

this kind of a code is not working. i get 0 in dipositCount which looks like the intial value of the observable.

[image]

Comment: if {{ last6MonthDepositCount$  | async }} is working , than .subscribe() will also work.

Comment: Can you share how you are using this deposit count ? There seems to be some issue with reactive approach in using depositCount.

Comment: i did this 
    this.last6MonthDepositCount$.subscribe(x => {  console.log(x); });
i get two values 0 and then 1 where 1 is the actual value i am looking for.

Comment: ok so i am using ChartJS chart where i have to setup 2 values in a pie chart.
this.myChartData.data.datasets[0].data = [this.depositCount, this.withdrawCount];

Comment: i updated a question. highlighted line is the one i am trying to assign the values to. i have a depositCount same exact way i have a widthdrawCount.

Comment: Check answer, you might have to tweak it according to your code.

Comment: Sure looking inti it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here **Reactive paradigm** is colliding with **imperative** one.

`myChart.data.datasets[0].data` gets called before `this.last6MonthDepositCount$.subscribe(x => this.dipositCount = x);` gives the final value.

What you need to do is :- initialize chartJs with initial/default value in `ngAfterViewInit` and also update `myChartData` in `this.last6MonthDepositCount$.subscribe()` method.

If you want to get results from 2 observables together, use **combineLatest**

```
const timerObservable1 = timer(0, 1000); 
    const timerObservable2 = timer(500, 1000); 
    const combinedTimers = combineLatest(timerObservable1, timerObservable2);
    combinedTimers.subscribe((value1, value2) => //DO something with both values together to update Chart);
```

Comment: As you said  this.last6MonthDepositCount$.subscribe(x => { console.log(x); }) gives two values. This is the issue. build your chart in .subscribe() method.

Comment: but i have two .subscribe one for deposit Value and one for withdraw 
which subscribe should i use. 

and do you mean like this
  this.last6MonthDepositCount$.subscribe(x => { this.depositCount = x;
                                                  this.myChartData.update();
});
?
myChartData  is already defined in ngAfterViewInit

Comment: Use combineLatest to combine result of both and build chartData there.

Comment: i figured out thankyou ! i am doing it as you described. i am doing both .subscribe s in inside ngAfterViewInit and both .subscribes have this.myChartData.update(); in it.